# What kind of device am I looking for?

Tags: button

Our water heater comes with a simple push button switch that needs to be pressed momentarily to start its recirculation pump. The push button seems to effectively touch two wires of a Cat5 cable to each other, completing some circuit. The wires don't need to stay touching each other once the initial contact is made. In other words, pressing that button for 1 second has the same effect as pressing the button for 10 seconds, or pressing it 10 times rapidly.

Since I already have a spare smart plug, I was hoping I could get some kind of a device that could be powered by that smart plug. When the smart plug turns on, the device could simulate the push button being pressed by effectively touching the two wires together. I can automate the smart plug such that it will not stay on more than a couple of seconds.

I *think* some kind of relay is what I am looking for, but am no expert, so would appreciate some specific guidance as to actual products that I should be searching for.

Comment: A relay, yes.With the coil rated for AC mains voltage so it can be powered by the smart plug. And a normally open contact rated for the same voltage and current as the supplied push button...

Comment: How about a cellphone charger cube, a 5V relay and a larger capacitor? plug the charger cube into the smart socket to get 5V regulated and reasonably safe power, then wire that 5V output in series with a capacitor and the relay coil. everytime the smart plug is activated the relay will close for a short time, determined by the cap and series resistance of the coil.

Comment: @Bryan, I would also do it your way, because the parts are cheaper, and there's no need to deal with dangerous voltages. the capacitor is optional - VSR says they will limit the switch-on time to be brief.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the answer by vu2nan is effectively doing the same thing, except that the relay in their diagram is working with a 120V input. The idea of isolating the high voltage at the smart outlet is certainly appealing. I do have several spare cellphone chargers lying around but I guess I would need to cut up the other end of the USB cable to get the correct two wires carrying 5V?

Comment: @VSR yup, or crack open the charger, but cutting the USB cord is easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 120 V ~ relay, with 1 set of C/O contacts, would do.

[image]

The relay 'NO' contact is to be wired across the existing push button switch in the heater.

Either the relay or the push button switch may be used.

Comment: Thank you. What does "1 C/O" stand for? Any chance you could point to an example product that I could look at?

Comment: Anytime! '1 C/O' stand's for 1 set of changeover contacts. You may search for '120 V ~ relay' (product suggestions are not permitted).

Comment: I found a relay that has two leads on the input side (for 110V) and two pairs of wires on the output side. One pair is labeled C1/NO1 and the other pair is labeled C2/NC2. I would simply ignore the C2/NC2 wires and just hook up C1 and NO1 to my push button, right?

Comment: Good, you were able to locate a relay with a 110 V AC coil . Yes, you need to connect 'C1' and 'NO1' to the push button.